# SQL top from score table with shots

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `score` with columns `ID, ID_Member, Shot, Points, ScoreSeconds, ScoreDate`

I need to get top 5 list members from this table and my results and show rank

I want to take members who reach best Points, with fewer ScoreSeconds and did it earlier than other members

Every member can have from 1 to 5 shots

I found some solutions but its work incorrect, *ID_Member = 4 is my id member*

```
select
    t.Rank + 1 as Rank,
    s.*
from (
    select
        s."ID_Member",
        max(s."Points") as Score_MaxPoints,
        max(s."ScoreSeconds") as Score_BestSeconds,
        max(s."ScoreDate") as Score_BestDate
    from "ScoreTest" as s
    where s."Points" > 0
        and s."ID_Member" <> 4
    group by s."ID_Member"  
    union select
        s."ID_Member",
        max(s."Points") as Score_MaxPoints,
        max(s."ScoreSeconds") as Score_BestSeconds,
        max(s."ScoreDate") as Score_BestDate
    from "Score" as s
    where s."Points" > 0
        and s."ID_Member" = 4
    group by s."ID_Member"
    order by
        2 desc,
        3 asc,
        4 asc
    limit 6
) as s
left join lateral (
select
    count(distinct o."ID_Member") as Rank
from "ScoreTest" as o
where o."ID_Member" <> s."ID_Member"
    and (    (o."Points" > s.Score_MaxPoints)
        or (     o."Points" = s.Score_MaxPoints 
                and o."ScoreSeconds" > s.Score_BestSeconds)
        or (     o."Points" = s.Score_MaxPoints 
                and o."ScoreSeconds" = s.Score_BestSeconds
                and o."ScoreDate" > s.Score_BestDate))
) as t on true
order by 1;
```

My table `score`:

```
create table if not exists "Score" (
  "ID" serial primary key,
  "ID_Member" integer,
  "Shot" integer,
  "Points" integer,
  "ScoreSeconds" integer,
  "ScoreDate" timestamp with time zone
)
```

Data for insert:

```
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (1, 1, 12, 77,  '2018-10-28 02:43:52.67967+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (1, 2, 27, 336, '2018-10-28 02:51:03.585303+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (2, 1, 9 , 66, '2018-10-28 18:47:28.352804+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (2, 2, 9 , 114, '2018-10-31 19:26:22.926129+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (2, 3, 10, 158, '2018-10-31 22:13:21.906929+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (3, 1, 22, 158, '2018-11-01 19:44:48.097315+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (3, 2, 22, 154, '2018-11-05 19:37:13.108119+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (4, 1, 10, 69, '2018-11-05 21:58:44.744138+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (4, 2, 18, 142, '2018-11-06 05:54:32.502891+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (5, 1, 37, 459, '2018-11-06 05:58:07.265676+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (5, 2, 23, 151, '2018-11-06 19:51:44.677442+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (6, 1, 17, 126, '2018-11-06 20:41:39.969008+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (7, 1, 90, 1114, '2018-11-06 20:45:09.458599+03');
insert into "ScoreTest" ("ID_Member", "Shot", "Points", "ScoreSeconds", "ScoreDate") values (8, 1, 23, 154, '2018-11-06 20:45:09.458599+03');
```

UPD: Added expected output

```
rank | member | points | seconds | date 
  1  |    7   |   90   |   1114  | 2018-11-06 20:45:09.458599+03
  2  |    5   |   37   |   459   | 2018-11-06 05:58:07.265676+03
  3  |    1   |   27   |   336   | 2018-10-28 02:51:03.585303+03
  4  |    8   |   23   |   154   | 2018-11-06 20:45:09.458599+03
  5  |    3   |   22   |   154   | 2018-11-05 19:37:13.108119+03
  6  |    4   |   18   |   142   | 2018-11-06 05:54:32.502891+03
```

Comment: Can you also provide expected output based on sample input?

Comment: @MayankPorwal done